# Enol content of acetylacetone and ethyl acetoacetate

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, tautomer

Why is the enol content of acetylacetone higher than that of acetoacetic ester? Hydrogen bonding stabilisation is present in enol form of both of them. I cannot figure out which factor makes one predominate over another.

Comment: Since the stabilisation by hydrogen bonding is about the same, we might as well just take it away. Try comparing acetone and ethyl acetate, which is more prone to enolisation?

Comment: @orthocresol Acetone is more prone to enolisation, but same problem persists, why is it more prone?

Comment: To enolise a carbonyl compound, you need to deprotonate the adjacent oxygen and push electrons into the C=O π* orbital, right? (And then you reprotonate on oxygen, but that doesn't make a difference here.) Well, in an ester, there's already one oxygen pushing electrons into that C=O π*. That makes it less interested in enolisation.

Comment: @orthocresol Got that! Accept my word of thanks.